# how do I solve this flutter problem The argument type 'dynamic Function(Map<String, bool>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

Tags: flutter

The argument type 'dynamic Function(Map<String, bool>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

was trying to pass a function of type Map<String, bool> to a function()

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the same issue